# Android CustomListView updated fields are repeating when scrolled down

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am having a problem in `customlist view`.

I have two `buttons` and one `textVie`w . Add and Subtract Buttons.
when click `Add` button the counter should be +1 and -1 respectively.

I have used a dummy string for checking whether it is actually updating the `textView` or not. But the problem is when I `scroll down` some of the items are having same value.

For example
1st item `TextView` is set to "HIII"
then if I scroll down the 11th ,21th ... is also set to "HIII"
Note: the max number that display can contain is 10 items so when I scroll down to 11th it is set to "HII".

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    int resource;
    //ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>();




    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewHolder mainHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            Log.e("GET-VIEW", " Creating Views");
           final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            holder.sub = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberTV);
            holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.textView.setText("HIII");
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
           mainHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}


class ViewHolder {

    Button add, sub;
    TextView textView;

}
```

Please Help me. I want to know how to set `tag` of one with other(I mean how you know you need to set the tag with the other object or view)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView recycles Views. It creates Views that will be re-used when scrolling down.

Thus, you have to call `setText()` and `setOnClickListener()` every time `getView()` is called, not only when button is clicked.

To achieve what you want, you have to store set text data in a model, like a `SparseArray` which maps positions to data.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    int resource;
    //ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>();

    // Your data map by position
    SparseArray<String> data = new SparseArray<>();


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            Log.e("GET-VIEW", " Creating Views");
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            holder.sub = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberTV);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(data.get(position));
        holder.add.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String text = "HIII";
                data.put(position, text);
                holder.textView.setText(text);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {

    Button add, sub;
    TextView textView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

write your onclick listener after else condition.

```
holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.textView.setText("HIII");
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it is not the full solution of the problem. When he scrolls, data will still be lost.

Comment: @YaroslavMytkalyk yes the data lost when I scroll down

Comment: @YaroslavMytkalyk I have tried your solution but I am getting null pointer excep. at  holder.textView.setText(data.get(position));

Comment: because the position is 10 and data doesnt contains any value at position 10

Comment: @Akshay Sood Yes, sorry, I misused the SparseArray method. You must use `data.put(position, text);` instead of `data.set(position, text);`. Answer updated.

Comment: @YaroslavMytkalyk I have used data.put(...) but still it is null pointer.. I have debug the app and found that when you are setting the textView the position is 10 but we haven't stored that much data yet

Comment: @AkshaySood that's okay. setText(null) is what you need to do. The problem is somwhere else. Can I have a stack trace? And please, let's discuss my answer under my answer comments.

Comment: @AkshaySood the problem was that you assigned `mainHolder` which was never used instead of `holder` if `convertView` was `not null`. I've updated my answer, removed `mainHolder` and removed the member listener as well, since I forgot that position was unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your getView function:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder mainHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        Log.e("GET-VIEW", " Creating Views");
       final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        holder.sub = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberTV);
        holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.textView.setText("HIII");
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
       mainHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

You edit the content of your holder `textView` and `add` Button only when you create a new Viewholder.
The first time your listview shows its items, there will be always a new view created (and a new Viewholder, too) for all visible cells.
As soon as you scroll down, the adapter will take a now-invisble cell (maybe the frist cell) and recycle it to show a now-visible cell. In this case, your `convertView` in getView won't be null anymore, as the view was recycled.
So you should handle all your text changes an Listener and so on outside of your `if` statement to manage both cases (recycled and new).
For example:

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        Log.e("GET-VIEW", " Creating Views");
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        holder.sub = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberTV);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
       mainHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView.setText("");
    holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.textView.setText("HIII");
            }
        });
```

**Edit**
To save your data in a sparse array like Yaroslav Mytkalyk suggested would be a better approach.
Anyway, you have to handle recycled views.

Comment: Good point, but every time he scrolls "HIII" will be lost for already clicked items. Check out my answer.